# why mysql just text type is avaible?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, blob

I was codding with php and use PDO/MySQL to store user uploaded files in DataBase

whene I set `contents` column to `TEXT` script work successfully
but `TEXT Type` Limit is 64kb and file size is near 700kbs
so I wanna to set column type to `MEDIUMTEXT` or any `BLOB` types
but when I do It , and run script , I see the data don't imported successfully !!! the problem can be where ?!

Comment: Reference: [**11.4.3 The BLOB and TEXT Types** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html)... the problem could be the setting of `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: @spencer7593 tnq dude but do you read my question currently ?!

Comment: dude did you read the documentation: **the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers.** ?!  If you want us to rule that out as an answer to "the problem can be where ?!", you need to show us the setting of `max_allowed_packet`... **`SELECT @@session.max_allowed_packet, @@global.max_allowed_packet`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [**11.4.3 The BLOB and TEXT Types** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html)

Excerpt:

> The maximum size of a BLOB or TEXT object is determined by its type, but the largest value you actually can transmit between the client and server is determined by the amount of available memory and the size of the communications buffers. You can change the message buffer size by changing the value of the `max_allowed_packet` variable, but you must do so for both the server and your client program.